# "Caged" complexity classes ?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

This is a somewhat frivolous question that popped up in my head after reading the various responses to ["What's the “smallest” complexity class for which a superlinear circuit bound is known?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/whats-the-smallest-complexity-class-for-which-a-superlinear-circuit-bound-is-k)".

Answers refer to $\mathsf{S_2 P}$, and when I looked at [the zoo entry for it](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aS#s2p), I discovered this:

> $\mathsf{S_2-EXP•P^{NP}}$: Don't Ask
>
> One of the caged classes of the
>   Complexity Zoo.
>
> Has been implicated in a collapse
>   scandal involving $\mathsf{AM}[\text{polylog}]$, $\mathsf{coNP}$,
>   and $\mathsf{EH}$

So now I'm intrigued. What's a caged complexity class, and what's the juicy scandal here :) ? The zoo has no references to clarify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Complexity Zoo has a reference to that result in the description of the class [AM[polylog]](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aA#ampolylog):

> […] [[SS04]](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Zooref#ss04) show that if AM[polylog] contains [coNP](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aC#conp), then [EH](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aE#eh) collapses to [S<sub>2</sub>-EXP•P<sup>NP</sup>](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aS#s2exppnp). ([[PV04]](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Zooref#pv04) improved the collapse to [AM<sub>EXP</sub>](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aA#amexp).)

In the Complexity Zoo, a class or a statement is caged when it looks very scary.  Examples of caged statements can be found in the descriptions of [coNP/poly](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aC#conppoly) and [SF<sub>*k*</sub>](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo%3aS#sfk) (not for the easily scared, reader discretion is advised).

Comment: excellent. That class itself is quite scary.

Comment: Still, how is that a scandal?

Comment: @Michaël: A collapse is a bad thing _by definition_.  See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/funny-tcs-related-papers-etc/3112#3112.  Although that article does not contain the word “scandal,” you will get the idea.

Comment: This is one of the funniest problem-answer pair in TCS SE :P

Comment: At least untill we start discussing Robertson-Seymour lemmas on hairy animals with balls